# use htaccess to stop processing request for favicon

Tags: .htaccess, favicon

i have two htaccess files, one for the root folder and another for the public folder. my problem is i'm getting an error because request for the favicon.ico is been processed. how do i stop the processing of the favicon?

below is my `.htaccess` files

:root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ^([^/]+)/?$ !^favicon\.ico

# Stop processing if already in the /public directory
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L]

# Static resources if they exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1 [L]

# Route all other requests
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

:public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ^([^/]+)/?$ !^favicon\.ico

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascripts/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stylesheets/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

the public folder is in the root folder